# Isometry in two dimensions

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor

> Let A be an isometry, then $g^{ij}=A^i{}_{k}A^j{}_l\,g^{kl}$ (1)
>
> First, consider an infinitesimal transformation $A=\exp(\epsilon \lambda )$
>
> Then express A by its power series to the first order in $\epsilon $ then plug in the expression into (1), drop all terms with $\epsilon ^2$ and find a condition for $\lambda ^{ij}$
>
> Also show that in two dimensions with a metric $g_{ij}$ the matrix $\lambda^i{}_k $ is proportional to
>
> $\begin{pmatrix} \lambda^1{}_1 & \lambda^1{}_2 \\ \lambda^2{}_1 & \lambda^2{}_2 \end{pmatrix} \propto \begin{pmatrix} g_{12} & g_{22} \\ -g_{11} & -g_{12} \end{pmatrix}$

$A=\mathbb{E}+\epsilon \lambda => [A]^i{}_j=\delta ^i_j + \epsilon \lambda ^i{}_j$

$g^{ij}=\delta^i_k \delta^j_lg^{kl}+\delta^i_k\lambda^j{}_l\epsilon g^{kl}+\epsilon\lambda^i{}_k\delta^j_lg^{kl} =>$

$g^{ij}=g^{ij}+\epsilon (\lambda^i{}_kg^{kj}+\lambda^j{}_lg^{il}) =>$
$\lambda^i{}_kg^{kj}=-\lambda^j{}_lg^{il} =>$
$\lambda^{ij}=- \lambda^{ji}$

However, the matrix for two dimensions doesn't fulfill this condition and I don't know what I've done wrong. Did I do a mistake?

Comment: Everything up until your last equation is OK. But the last equation $\lambda^{jl} = - \lambda^{ik}$ does not make sense; the indices don't match. You probably mean $\lambda^i{}_k g^{kj} = \lambda^{ij}$ etc.

Comment: @Kekks *I don't know how to do that here* Give a look at my edit. Also
for the "\,"

Comment: @ElioFabri Thanks, I changed it.

Comment: @HansMoleman You're right. But this condition doesn't apply to the given matrix neither.

Comment: You're writing $\lambda{}^j{}_l g^{il} = \lambda^{ij}$. Might want to reconsider that equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isometries for any metric in any dimension are found to be solutions of the Killing equation, which can be written for an infinitesimal coordinate transformation $x^i\rightarrow x^i+\xi^i$ in the form:$$ \xi_{i;j}=-\xi_{j;i}$$ where the semi-colon indicates the covariant derivative. So if you interpret this as a matrix the correct relation should be $\lambda^{ij}=-\lambda^{ji}$. The matrix should be anti-symmetric.

For the second part of the question (restricted to two dimensions) one can use the generic form for $\lambda^{ij} = \left(\begin{array}{c c} 0 & f(x,y) \\ -f(x,y) & 0\end{array}\right).$ Lowering on index corresponds to multiplication with the metric tensor $g_{ij}$. One finds $$\left(\begin{array}{c c} 0 & f(x,y) \\ -f(x,y) & 0\end{array}\right)\cdot \left(\begin{array}{c c} g_{11} & g_{12} \\ g_{12} & g_{22}\end{array}\right) = f\cdot \left(\begin{array}{c c} g_{12} & g_{22} \\ -g_{11} & -g_{12}\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: How do I shot that the proportionality holds?
I see that when mutiplying $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and the metric tensor that i get to the matrix I am supposed to show proportionality with. But being antisymmetric doesnt imply that is has to have that exact form, does it?

Comment: Antisymmetric for the twodimensional case means $\left(\begin{array} {c c} 0 & f(x,y)\\-f(x,y) & 0 \end{array}\right)$. That's why it only is proportional and not equal to.

Comment: So proportionality means that the factor can be a matrix aswell? In this case the metric tensor is the factor.

Comment: No, the factor is f. The first product is the transition from $\lambda^{ij}$ to $\lambda^{i}_j$. Lowering the index corresponds to multiplication with $g_{ij}$. If you write $\lambda^{ij}g_{jk}=\lambda^{i}_k$, this is nothing but the matrix multiplication written above.

Comment: Ah, now I got it. Thanks.